# PyQt - using QSqlRelationalTableModel - model.select() populates with QSQLITE, not psycopg2

Tags: pyqt4

In this common example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql
import psycopg2 as psycopg
import sys

#try:
conn = psycopg.connect("dbname='metalarc1' user='postgres' host='192.168.1.136'       
    password='admin' port='5433'");
#except:
#    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

def initializeModel(model):
#    cur.execute("""select * from employee""")
#    rows = cur.fetchall()
    model.setTable("employee")
    model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    model.setRelation(2, QtSql.QSqlRelation('city', 'id', 'name'))
    model.setRelation(3, QtSql.QSqlRelation('country', 'id', 'name'))

    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
    model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
    model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "City")
    model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Country")
    model.select()

def createView(title, model):
    view = QtGui.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(view))
    view.setWindowTitle(title)

    return view

def createRelationalTables():
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    cur.execute("""create table employee(id int primary key not null, name 
           varchar(20), city int, country int)""")
    cur.execute("""insert into employee values(1, 'Espen', 5000, 47)""")
    cur.execute("""insert into employee values(2, 'Harald', 80000, 49)""")
    cur.execute("""insert into employee values(3, 'Sam', 100, 41)""")
    cur.execute("""create table city(id int primary key not null, name varchar(20))""")
    cur.execute("""insert into city values(100, 'San Jose')""")
    cur.execute("""insert into city values(5000, 'Oslo')""")
    cur.execute("""insert into city values(80000, 'Munich')""")
    cur.execute("""create table country(id int primary key not null, name     varchar(20))""")
    cur.execute("""insert into country values(41, 'USA')""")
    cur.execute("""insert into country values(47, 'Norway')""")
    cur.execute("""insert into country values(49, 'Germany')""")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    createRelationalTables()
    model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    initializeModel(model)
    view = createView("Relational Table Model", model)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The tables get created fine and populated.  But the model.select() returns False and the view pops up blank (no column headings or data).
When I run the same code with the QSQLITE database it works fine.  I feel like it must be very simple since the data is there if I:

```
cur.execute("""select * from employee""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows[0]
(1, 'Espen', 5000, 47)
```

I could sure use some help - been struggling with this for 2 days.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect to your PostgreSQL database using `QSqlDatabase` rather than importing psycopg2.

A (pythonised) example of connecting [from the docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqldatabase.html):

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("acidalia")
db.setDatabaseName("customdb")
db.setUserName("mojito")
db.setPassword("J0a1m8")
ok = db.open()
```

When you use `QSqlQuery` and `QSqlRelationalTableModel.setTable()` they use your default `QSqlDatabase` connection, unless you specify a connection name when creating them. In your example above you don't have one - I'm guessing when you use your 'QSQLITE' database it's a `QSqlDatabase`?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think I am getting closer but still no data.  A couple of things:

Comment: I still don't see how QPSQL or ODBC can work without a driver. I do have

Comment: Which platform are you on? Under Windows using the PyQt binary installer from http://riverbankcomputing.co.uk you should have qsqlpsql4.dll in your <python dir>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\sqldrivers folder. Calling QSqlDatabase.drivers() should tell you what you have available.

Comment: Yes, I have qsqlpsql4.dll in the sqldrivers folder. QSqlDatabase.drivers() gets me QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7 (and QSQLITE etc.)

Comment: Great, that should work then. Replace your psycopg.connect(...) with my db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL") example. Change the connection details to match yours and model.setTable("employee") should make use of the database connection.

Comment: Thanks again Gary, what a relief to get this working.  Still learning about OOP - old school - trying to port a legacy WatcomSQL MRP application I wrote 18 yrs ago for my customers.  Quite a learning curve.  Tempted to use VBA but worry that I'll regret it later.  Keith